# I can’t upload an MP4 file to folder 'htdocs'

Tags: html, css, video, mp4, htdocs

I'm trying to upload my website, but my MP4 file is not uploading. I keep getting this message:

> _images\no-sound.mp4 - error occurred - Access denied.  The file may not exist locally,  may be open in another program, or there could be a local permission problem.

> File activity incomplete. 1 file(s) or folder(s) were not completed. 
> Files with errors: 1
> _images\no-sound.mp4

This is my code for the website:

```
<div class="fullscreen-video-wrap">
    <video src="_images/no-sound.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted></video>
</div>
```

The website works on preview mode, btw.

Comment: Re *"I'm trying to upload my website"*: Do you mean *"I'm trying to upload* ***to*** *my website"*?

Answer (score -1):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Try to debug with this.

Or if the problem persists it could be because you are referring to a video file which the server does not have the access to.